# How can I update or save a record using the same HTML form in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, formhelper

This is my first time trying to update a record in Ruby on Rails, so thanks in advance for your help. I have an HTML form. Within the form, I want the option to update a record in the newsavedmaps table in MySQL.

The form is much more complex than the below, but it has this basic structure:

**maptry.html.erb**

```
    <form id="createaMap" action="/newsavedmaps" method="post">                 
    <label for="savemap_name">Map Title</label>
    <input id="savemap_name" name="newsavedmapname" size="30" type="text" value="New Map"></p>
    <%= link_to 'Update Saved Map', @newsavedmap, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :put %>
    <input type="submit" id="savethismap" value="Save As New Map">
    </form>
```

**edit.html.erb from the newsavedmaps views folder**

```
    <h1>Editing newsavedmap</h1>

    <% form_for(@newsavedmap) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>

      <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Show', @newsavedmap %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', newsavedmaps_path %>
```

If I start with a new record, save map works.

However, if I start where @newsavedmap is defined already and I click the "update saved map" link, it just takes me to "/newsavedmaps/ID".

I know that I can use form helpers, but I'm trying to avoid a solution that relies on recreating the entire form since it's set up in HTML. Again, I appreciate your help!

**Edit 1**

Here is the log from my attempt using Bigxiang's code. It looks like the right information is being sent, but the record is not being updated. Note that there are two start and two end inputs, and either takes the start or end address, which is why two are left blank below.

Is there something else I should check?

```
    Processing NewsavedmapsController#update (for IP at DATE) [PUT]
    Parameters: {"endhere"=>"", "endthere"=>"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC 20500", "newsavedmapname"=>"New Map test", "startthere"=>"1201 Farragut Street Northwest, Washington, DC 20011", "id"=>"74", "starthere"=>"", "optimize"=>"on"} 
    Redirected to http://site.com/maptry
     Completed in 11ms (DB: 0) | 302 Found [http://site.com/newsavedmaps/74]
```

**NewsavedmapsController#update**

```
    def update
       @newsavedmap = Newsavedmap.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @newsavedmap.update_attributes(params[:newsavedmap])
            flash[:notice] = 'Newsavedmap was successfully updated.'
            format.html { redirect_to "/maptry" }
            format.xml  { head :ok }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "edit" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @newsavedmap.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

**edit.html.erb for newsavedmaps**

In my routes, I have map.resources :newsavedmaps and I created a folder in my views for Newsavedmaps. In that, I've got an edit.html.erb file that looks like the below:

```
    <h1>Editing newsavedmap</h1>

    <% form_for(@newsavedmap) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_messages %>

    id: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :id %><br />
    itinerary_id: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :itinerary_id %><br />
    start: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :start %><br />
    start_lat: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :start_lat %><br />
    start_long: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :start_long %><br />
    start_masterlocation_id: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :start_masterlocation_id %><br />
    end: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :end %><br />
    end_lat: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :end_lat %><br />
    end_long: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :end_long %><br />
    end_masterlocation_id: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :end_masterlocation_id %><br />
    name: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :name %><br />
    optimize: <%= text_field :newsavedmap, :optimize %><br />

      <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
      </p>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to 'Show', @newsavedmap %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', newsavedmaps_path %>
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error when I try and go to /newsavedmaps/ID . Error is " undefined method `endhere'." I'm not sure if this is the right approach, however.

Comment: Obviously your model doesn't have a `endhere` method.  Does the column exist in your db?

Comment: Thanks, bdares. My bad; I used the wrong column headings. With the edit.html.erb version I fixed above, I can manually edit the fields and submit the form, and it works. However, submitting the form with maptry.html.erb still gives the same log code without any change to the record: `Processing NewsavedmapsController#update (for IP at DATE) [PUT] Parameters: {"endhere"=>"", "endthere"=>"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC 20500", "newsavedmapname"=>"New Map test", "startthere"=>"1201 Farragut Street Northwest, Washington, DC 20011", "id"=>"74", "starthere"=>"", "optimize"=>"on"}`

Comment: Looking again at your form, you're not associating the inputs with the model correctly.  Look at @Bigxiang's answer and see how his form is built differently from yours.  His form should work correctly.

Comment: Bdares, I see that he uses the individual form handler fields, like <%= f.text_field :newsavedmapname %>. Are you saying that there is a difference between that and my fields in maptry.html.erb, like `<input id="savemap_name" name="newsavedmapname" size="30" type="text" value="New Map"></p>` ?

Comment: The generated form after association with a model will have attributes like `name="newsavedmap[endhere]"` instead of `name="endhere"`, try both and take a look with firebug

Comment: Neither approach worked for me. Can't create a new record, either: `Processing NewsavedmapsController#create (for IP at DATE TIME) [POST]
  Parameters: {"newsavedmap"=>{"endthere"=>"", "endhere"=>"1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC 20500", "startthere"=>"", "newsavedmapname"=>"New Map test", "optimize"=>"on", "starthere"=>"1201 Farragut Street Northwest, Washington, DC 20011"}}

ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: endhere):`

Answer (score 1):

I think there are several problems here.

The first, you can't submit form using

`<%= link_to 'Update Saved Map', @newsavedmap, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :put %>`

because `link_to` with `method` will generate a dynamic form and submit it, so your form will not be submitted.

The second, I am not sure where you want to submit when update a defined @newsavedmap.

If you want to submit to "/newsavedmaps/ID" and execute `update` method of the controller to save the record, I suggest using this

```
<%= form_for @newsavedmap, :html=>{:id=>'createaMap'} do |f|%>
    End Here: <%= f.text_field :endhere %><br />
    End There: <%= f.text_field :endthere %><br />
    Newsavedmap Name: <%= f.text_field :newsavedmapname %><br />
    Start There: <%= f.text_field :startthere %><br />

    Start There: <%= f.text_field :starthere %><br />
    <input type="submit" id="savethismap" value="Save">
<% end %>
```

keep all the content of your form, just modify the form tag to form_for, so if your @newsavedmap is a new record, the save button will execute `create` method of the controller, if @newsavedmap is a defined record, the save button will execute `update` method of the controller with correct parameters.

Comment: Bigxiang, I've updated the code, but I'm still running into a problem getting the record to update. Do you have any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: Hi, can you show me the code of NewsavedmapsController#update?

Comment: Also added the edit.html.erb. Originally, the edit.html.erb for newsavedmaps didn't have any of the text input fields, so I'm guessing that was part of the problem.

Comment: Hi, Bigxiang. Please see my comment in response to bdares above.